# Have Django traceback pinpoint where error occurred?

Tags: django

I have two questions about Django tracebacks.

First, if I have a traceback like the following, I can see that the error is occurring in the 'review_new_profile' view as shown in the second traceback error
below.  Is it possible to tell Django to also display the line number in that view where the error occurred?

```
/srv/http/example.com/venvs/725be8a8537aeef8021231ba68de3184bbd547b1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
1.  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

/srv/http/example.com/repo/profile/views.py in review_new_profile
1.  user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid'])

/srv/http/example.com/venvs/725be8a8537aeef8021231ba68de3184bbd547b1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in __getitem__
1.  return self._session[key]
```

What I'd like to see is something like the following where '540' is the line number in the views.py:

```
/srv/http/example.com/repo/profile/views.py in review_new_profile (540)
1.  user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid'])
```

Second, am I correct in in thinking that the error actually occurred at the bottom-most line?  So an interpretation of this trace is that Django was trying to generate a response to a request but when it tried to get a user instance for a given uid, it couldn't find the uid in the session?  In other words, the error actually occurred on the last line in the traceback, where Django was trying to get the uid (key) from the session?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, Django does show the line. In your case, those `1`s are the line numbers. The real question is why they are all `1`s.

Second question: you are correct. The exception occurred on the last line.
Basically, when you did `request.session['uid']`, it tried to call that `session` object's `__getitem__` method. Somewhere inside that `__getitem__`, there is this line:

```
   return self._session[key]
```

This is what gave the error.